# Fade unfocused GNU Emacs frame (X window)

Tags: linux, emacs

Is it possible to make GNU Emacs 24 dim unfocused windows a bit?  For example, I can set my `rxvt-unicode` clients to become darker when their windows don't have focus with this string in `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
URxvt*fading: 50
```

It greatly reduces discomfort when you have a lot of terminal windows on 2+ monitors.  I would like a similar feature in Emacs, but couldn't google up anything.

[Here is how it looks like with urxvt (png, 1.43 MB)](http://nixternal.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/urxvt1.png)

Comment: Do you actually mean windows, or do you mean frames?

Comment: @Thomas Emacs frames are windows in X terminology.  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frames.html

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I'm asking. Looking at the screenshot, it looks like you're talking about Emacs windows, but perhaps you're using a tiling window manager and thus actually mean Emacs frames. (Probably, though, you mean both anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

I do something similar:

```
(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha '(100 60))
(aput 'default-frame-alist 'alpha '(100 60))
```

which sets the alpha value of the selected frame to 100, and an unselected frame to 60, making it somewhat transparent.  I haven't tested to confirm that works for other frame-parameters.

Comment: Works with OS X Emacs.app too. (24.1.5)

Comment: Actually, I should have stated, that's what I'm using is Emacs.app.  Thanks.